# Magento add custom button to Order create page

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a button to the order create page in Magento, next to "Add Products by Sku" and "Add Products".  I've tried adding $this-_addbutton code to the construct function of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items. But doing that causes that section to show up.

Here's where I want to add the button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't say that it is proper answer but yes it will work for now.

In Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items write this code in the beginning of method getButtonsHtml()

```
$this->_buttons[] = array(
    'id'=>'add_products_by_sku',
    'title'=>'Add Products By SKU',
    'label'=>'Add Products By SKU',
    'class'=>'add',
    'onclick'=>'',
);
```